# Use property from command line for resources filtering

Tags: maven

I am using maven and want to write some maven properties to a properties file by using resource filtering.
This seems to work fine unless I try to overwrite certain properties from the command line.

For instance in the example below I set the property `application-type` to MIXED in the pom.xml but I want to overwrite it with BATCH from the command line. The filtering still writes MIXED to my properties file even though I provide the property like this: `-Dapplication-type=BATCH`

How can I write the property values which are provided via command line parameters to the properties file?

Project structure:

```
.
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        `-- resources
            `-- application.properties
```

pom.xml (irrelevant parts omitted):

```xml
<properties>
        <!-- ApplicationType should be provided via maven parameter. Allowed values: MIXED, DIALOG, BATCH -->
        <application-type>MIXED</application-type>
</properties>

<build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <!-- Apply filtering to write maven properties into properties file -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <!-- ... -->        
</build>
```

application.properties:

```
application-type=${application-type}
```

and i am calling it like this:
`mvn clean process-resources -Dapplication-type=BATCH`

However the resulting application.properties (in target/classes/application.properties) contains:
`application-type=MIXED`
instead of the expected
`application-type=BATCH`

Comment: I recommend first to remove `<sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>`, `<testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>` and also `<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>`...Furthermore is this a spring boot application?

Comment: No, it is not a spring boot application.

Comment: I will remove `<sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>`, `<testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>` and `<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>` and see if everything works fine still. I'm not sure why this is here even.

Comment: Is this a spring boot application?